# How long can a titan shifter stay in a titan form?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In *Attack on Titan*, most titan shifters are only shown in their titan form for a while, but apparently, Pieck can stay in her titan form for up to 2 months.

How long can a titan shifter stay in a titan form? What about Eren?

Note: this is not about the 13-year curse, but the duration of the transformation.

Answer (score 1):

Although I am an AOT enthusiast, I, too, am unsure. If you count Annie in, she was in a dormant stage for 4 years since her capture and Eren's rumbling. I'm assuming she was using her titian powers, because it would have been impossible for her to stay alive without suffocating, starving, and dehydrating. However, When Ymir was given the Titan power, she roamed outside for a while before going into a hibernation state for around 1,800 years all the while remaining in Titan form the entire time. Since Eren has inherited Ymir's powers, I'm assuming that he can at least last around roughly the same or half the time, but only if he went into a hibernation state like Ymir. This is all speculation on my part, however, and the time cannot be actually determined.

Comment: I think you mistook founder Ymir with Jaw Ymir. Jaw Ymir was around in her form for around 60 years. And the royal Ymir won't make Erens life longer. Curse is curse.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends. For example , Pieck can stay in her Cart Titan form for months (though I think she's built for endurance ) and I don't think I've seen loads of the characters stay in their titan form for more than a day . However, that could be due to a lack of inexperience . My guess is that once they have used up all their energy as a titan they simply transform back